# HTML HREF, how to set relative path from the root (without using ".." to move up)?

Tags: html, asp.net, href, absolute-path

For Example, if I have this in my aspx file:

```
<link href="../Css/StyleSheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

with ".." indicate to go up one directory level.

Whenever I move the aspx page to different directory level, I have to set it again. 
How do I set it so that it will be relative to the root of the project folder?
(So that either if I move the project folder to somewhere else and/or moving the aspx page to upper/lower directory level, I won't have to set it again?

Answer (score 10):

You should be able to use Page.ResolveUrl:

```
    <link href="<%= Page.ResolveUrl("~/Css/StyleSheet.css") %>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Or possibly turn it into server control and be able to use the tilde:

```
    <link href="~/Css/StyleSheet.css" runat="server">
```

Comment: I used your method and this is what I got "The Controls collection cannot be modified because the control contains code blocks (i.e. <% ... %>)"

Comment: You might have <% %> blocks in the header of your page or in your master page if your using one. You should be able to replace the code block with <%# instead of <%=, but you will need to add Page.Header.DataBind(); in the page load. The second method should work without issue and the tilde will tell the link to start from the root of the site.

Comment: I tried the second one and it doesn't work.The first one is too complicated.

Comment: `<img runat="server" ... />` not same that `<img  ... />`  `<a runat="server" ... />` not same that `<a  ... />` . ***not same behaviour*** for `runat=server` than not

Answer (score 0):

You can start your URLs with `/`:

```
<link href="/Css/StyleSheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Comment: I tried this, it works while in Debug Mode in Visual Studio, but when I published to IIS, it didn't work.

Comment: @J-CSharper It should work. Are you sure you used the correct path (e.g. */StyleSheet.css* or */Foo/Bar/Css/StyleSheet.css*) ??

Comment: This is the absolute path: MyProjectName/Css/StyleSheet.css

Comment: Then (if MyProjectName is inside the root folder), you should use /MyProjectName/Css/StyleSheet.css

Comment: @J-CSharper Instead of using mydomain.com/MyProjectName/Css/StyleSheet.css, you could use subdomains: MyProjectName.foobar.com/Css/StyleSheet.css . Or maybe you could use a [`<base>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base) element

Comment: I'm okay with having to use the ProjectName in the path, however, most of my project are having the same folder structure, I don't want to go to every one of them to make the change.

Comment: Sorry, Let me retract my comment, it's only work with src= , not with href

Comment: @J-CSharper I can't give any example of `<base>` because I have never used it, and maybe there are better solutions, so I think you should ask another question about it.

Comment: Not valid if you have Virtual Directory like `/v1/`, `/v2/`